# SDE with $a(t,x) = |x|^{\alpha}$ and $a(t,x) =a(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

- Let $a,b : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be Borel functions.
- Let  $X$ be the solution of

$$ X_t= \int_{0}^t a(s,X_s) dW_s + \int_{0}^t b(s,X_s) ds , t \in[0,T]$$ We call it $SDE(a,b)$

1. If $a(t,x) = |x|^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha > \dfrac12$ and $b$ Lipschitz, does $SDE(a,b)$ admit pathwise uniqueness? What about uniqueness in law?
2. Suppose $a(t,x)=a(x)$ and $b(t,x)=0$. Does $SDE(a,0, \delta_{x_0})$ admit existence and uniqueness in law?

---

Some conditions are given [here](https://uma.ensta-paris.fr/conf/tipe/2011/talks/tipe2012-Russo,Francesco-article_sde.pdf) and in Singular Stochastic Differential Equations by Alexander S. Cherny and Hans-Jürgen Engelbert.

1. Yamada-Watanabe criterion?
2. We  use the Engelbert-Schmidt  criterion.
   For a Borel function, we define

- $Z(\sigma)= \{x \in\mathbb{R} | \sigma(x)=0 \}$
- $I(\sigma)$ the set of real numbers $x$ such that $\int_{x - \epsilon}^{x + \epsilon} \dfrac{dy}{ \sigma^2(y) }= \infty, \forall \epsilon >0$
- $I(a) \subset Z(a)$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for existence in law.
- $I(a) = Z(a)$  is a necessary and sufficient condition for existence and uniqueness in law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Watanabe criterion states that if

- We suppose that $b$ is Lipschitz and
- there exists $h : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ strictly increasing continuous such that
- $h(0)=0$
- $\int_{x - \epsilon}^{x + \epsilon} \dfrac{dy}{ h^2(y) }= \infty, \forall \epsilon >0$
- $ |a(t,x) - a(t,y)| \leq h(x-y)$

Then we have pathwise existence.

With $\alpha \geq \frac12$ and   $a(t,x)= x^{\alpha}$ the conditions are verified according to this [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200967/x-alpha-y-x-alpha-geq-y-alpha-for-alpha-geq-frac12)