# $|x| ^\alpha + |y-x|^\alpha \geq |y|^\alpha$ for $1 \geq \alpha \geq \frac12$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

We want to prove that $\forall x,y$ and $ 1 \geq \alpha \geq \frac12$
$$|x| ^\alpha + |y-x|^\alpha \geq |y|^\alpha$$

Is there an alternative proof ?

---

- We consider for $\beta \geq 1$,  $\Phi(t)= (a+t)^\beta - a^\beta - t^\beta$
- $\Phi$ is increasing (its derivative is positive) and $\Phi(0)=0$
- Therefore $(a+t)^\beta - a^\beta - t^\beta \geq 0$
- then we choose  $a=x-y, t=y, \beta= \frac{1}{\alpha}$ so $\alpha \leq 1$
- We obtain $ | (x-y)^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha}|^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\geq |x-y| +|y| \geq |x|$
- $|x-y|^{\alpha} + |y|^{\alpha} \geq |x|^{ \alpha}$
- By exchanging $x$ and $y$, we have $||x|^{\alpha} -|y|^{\alpha} | \leq |x-y| ^ { \alpha}$

Comment: Quick sanity check . Pick $x=y/2$. Then your inequality becomes $$ \frac{2}{2^\alpha} \vert y\vert^\alpha \geq \vert y\vert^\alpha.$$ So you need $\alpha\leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have changed. Why this condition does not appear in the proof ?

Comment: It does. You assume $\beta\geq 1$ and set then $\beta=1/\alpha$.

Comment: The fifth bullet point is also not quite correct. The function $t\mapsto t^{1/\alpha}$ is not linear.

Comment: It should be correct now.

Comment: This is more or less how I did it here [for $a\in]0,1]$ the function $X^a$ is a-Hölderian](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2508788/399263)

Comment: For $0<p<1$, you have the inequality $(a+b)^p\leq a^p+b^p$ for all $a,b\geq0$. This can be proved by looking at $\phi(x)=(1+x)^p-x^p$. Differentiation gives $\phi'(x)=p((1+x)^{p-1}-x^{p-1})<0$ for $x>0$. Hence $\phi$ is monotone decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ and so, $\phi(x)<\phi(0)=1$ for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In this proof, $x$ and $y$ can be vectors.)
**I assume that** $0\lt\alpha\leq1.$
The inequality is valid for $y=0,$ so assume $y\ne0$ and let $t={|x|\over |y|}.$
By the triangle inequality, we can replace $|y-x|$ by $\big||y|-|x|\big|.$
Dividing both sides of the original inequality by $|y|^\alpha,$ we get
$$f(t):=t^{\alpha}+(1-t)^{\alpha}\ge1 \ \ \ \text{for }\ 0\leq t \leq1 \tag1$$
and
$$g(t):=t^{\alpha}+(t-1)^{\alpha}\ge1 \ \ \ \text{for }\ t\ge1 \tag2$$
For $0\lt t\le 1,\ t^{\alpha-1}\geq1.$ Therefore, $t^{\alpha}\geq t$ and
$(1-t)^{\alpha}\geq 1-t,$ so that (1) follows easily.
The minimum value of $g$ is $g(1)=1$ because $g'$ is always positive. Thus, (2) holds.